# Why is Beresheet doing a only a one-way trip?

Tags: mars, the-moon, lander, beresheet

Why is the [SpaceIL Lunar Lander](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/beresheet.htm) doing a one-way trip? Is that a common project to do nowadays, to send landers to Mars and the Moon without returning them?

Comment: Maybe because of the smaller budget that drove to have a lighter payload which did not allow for extra fuel?

Comment: This is a "show" mission more than a scientific mission, and a successful landing and walkabout it sufficient to make it a spectacular success for a first time deep space mission for this agency. Returning to Earth is just an opportunity to fail, whereas success may bring interest in a follow-on mission.

Comment: It is very common for Mars landers not to return. In fact, it is ubiquitous.

Comment: One way trips are and have always been the norm in space exploration.  The few sample return missions (mentioned by @Hobbes) are very much the exceptions.

Answer (score 18):

A one-way trip is much simpler and much cheaper than a return mission.

- a return mission is more complicated because it has to do more
- a return mission is much heavier (because of the extra systems, and the fuel needed for the return capsule) which means it needs a bigger launcher which is more expensive

We have had no sample return missions from any planet. There were a few from the Moon (Apollo and Luna), and a few from objects like asteroids and comets (e.g. Hayabusa).

The SpaceIL mission is a small, low-cost mission done as a technology demonstration. A return mission would have cost 10x more.